# Workweek start and end date

Tags: ironpython

I need to write a script that gives me a range of days from today back to the beginning of the work week. In other words, say that today is Tuesday August 9th and I click on my button I should get two dates, a  start date equals to "8/7/2011" and end date equals to today or "8/9/2011"
I already got the code to give me a week prior to today like:

```
startDate = System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(System.TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0))
endDate   = System.DateTime.Now
```

I just don't know how to make it get the current week and subtract from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether my code helps you or not but you can try the following sample:

```
from System import DateTime, TimeSpan, DayOfWeek

endDate = DateTime.Now
startDate = DateTime.Now
span = TimeSpan()
daySpan = span.FromDays(1)

while startDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday:
    startDate -= daySpan

print startDate, endDate
```

Think it could be done the easier way as well as using standard python datetime module.